# Node.js process restart

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna know if theres a general function or can be made a function to restart the process; just like `process.disconnect()` but in this case it will restart the script when the function is called.

Comment: No, there is nothing of the sort you should do it from outside the process anyway. You can just `process.exit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-restart node app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417528/how-to-auto-restart-node-app)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally process managers are used to (automatically) restart processes, such as monit, PM2, nodemon, forever, etc.

However, you *could* restart from the process itself by simply spawning a detached child process that waits some period of time and then executes the same script. You could do this as a combination of two commands, one to sleep and the other the current command line, or you could simply incorporate the sleep into your script. An example of the latter:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

(function main() {
  if (process.env.process_restarting) {
    delete process.env.process_restarting;
    // Give old process one second to shut down before continuing ...
    setTimeout(main, 1000);
    return;
  }

  // ...

  // Restart process ...
  spawn(process.argv[0], process.argv.slice(1), {
    env: { process_restarting: 1 },
    stdio: 'ignore',
  }).unref();
})();
```

On Windows, you may need to add `detached: true` to your `spawn()` configuration object though. For *nix, this usually shouldn't be necessary.

One thing to keep in mind though is that any restarted process won't have access to the terminal anymore, if the original process was started in the foreground.

Also, you could eliminate the delay and `process.env` checking if your script does not use any resources that can only be used by at most one process at any given time.

One final note: if your process crashes abnormally, due to memory exhaustion, triggering a C++ assertion, a V8 bug, etc., your process won't restart obviously (even if you have an `'unhandledException'` event handler set for `process`). To account for these situations you pretty much need some sort of external mechanism to restart the process.

Comment: Extra Karma Points for including the `detached: true`! Thanks, I did not know about that!

Answer (score 2):

In case you start your script as a system daemon (with upstart or systemd for example), you could just `process.exit()` and let those take care of recreating a new process for you.

Comment: `process.exit()` just closes the script, i need to restart the script with the command.

Comment: @Maxsanc1 When you close a process started by a daemon (such as systemd or nssm) it will automatically restart if you've configured it to do so,